# emacs mysterious mark mode, cannot quit with C-g

Tags: emacs

I use emacs 24.3.1 on ubuntu 14.04, and Xshell to access the console.
Usually, I mark a region with the following step:

- C-@ to set the mark, and the minibuffer will say "Mark Set"
- M-f to expand the region
- C-w or M-w to use the region
- C-g to quit the mark mode

That all works fine, but sometimes, I run into the mysterious mark mode, when I just use M-f(or M-b) to move the point, the minibuffer says "Mark Set" and the text is selected. Even after click C-g or Esc many times, the Mark state cannot disappear, but it do disappear after some time of editing, and I don't known how.

*Here is the question:*

1. Is the strange mark mode normal, please tell me how I accientally run into it?
2. Is there a way to quit?

Comment: When this happens, what is your major mode? Try running `M-: major-mode`. I bet your major mode is overwriting M-f to its own function (e.g. `java-forward-word` instead of simply `forward-word`). This function may be poorly written and set the mark when it shouldn't.

Comment: @BrianMalehorn My major mode is **c-mode**, I'm also using _ede_ and _semantic_ minor mode.

Comment: What does `C-h k M-f` say? It should tell you want `M-f` is bound to. Also, what does it say when the mark is set (`C-@ C-h k M-f`)?

Comment: @BrianMalehorn They both say `M-f runs the command forward-word, which is an interactive built-in function in 'syntax.c'`, I did some edit to get into the problem mode, I check the key binding there, the result is all the same. Also C-g is bound to `keyboard-quit`, which seems all right.

Comment: By "mark state", can you confirm whether you are referring to an *active region* (i.e. the marked region is *highlighted*) ?

Comment: @phils Yes, it is highlighted, and I can _kill&yank_ the text in the region. Only `M-f` and `M-b` make the region selected, while `C-f` and `C-b` just move the point.

Comment: @phils I reviewed this question and found that my last answer to your comment is wrong, sorrry for that. By "mark state" I mean `M-f` alone can still make the text highlighted, `C-g` will cancel the highlight but can't make `M-f` go back to normal.

Comment: I think I found the reason. It happens only when Caps Lock is on. So actually I was using `M-F` to move forward. I haven't seen any documentation on this, and `C-h k M-F` just give me doc of `M-f`. Anyway, problem solved, thanks for your help @BrianMalehorn @phils.